# Deleted an important line in the designer script

Tags: c#

I'm studying computer science and working on a project.

Within my project, I made an ABSOLUTELY stupid mistake and deleted a line of code in the designer.cs, and now I have nearly 400 errors. Unfortunately for me, it ended up saving and closing which means I can't revert any changes made, I looked for backups but can't find any.

I have no idea what that line of code was, and I don't want to redo the entire project by copying and pasting. Any help if possible is much appreciated! I hope I explained it enough

[The missing line is the first one after initialize component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfxXJ.png)

Edit: [Errors list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug3Cl.png)

Comment: _"I'm studying computer science"_ I guess they probably don't teach you to **always use source control**, so this is a valuable lesson. Always use source control.

Comment: source control all the way. Or a regular backup, at the very least

Comment: unfortunately, the teacher didn't teach me anything with coding and I have to learn by myself.My mistake

Comment: use git to avoid such errors.

Comment: By the way, it's nearly always better to use text rather than screen shots on Stack Overflow.  Show code as `code` (by indenting 4 spaces).  For your errors, you can get a text version of all the errors if you look in the "Output" pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You removed your system refrence, Add it back by right click References -> Add Reference

Under Assemblies , search for System

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you So MUCH! Lifesavers you all are.

Answer (score -1):

Based on errors in the screenshot, I think you simply need to add `using System;`  to the top of the file.